# Send SMS Message with Twilio purchased number

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio, sms-gateway

> I have purchased number but i am not able to send SMS message its
>   giving bad request 400.By using trial number i am able to send SMS below
>   i am using AFNewtorking for API or is there any other method to call
>   api for purchase valid number

```
NSString *kTwilioSID = @" ";
    NSString *kTwilioSecret = @" ";
    NSString *kFromNumber = @"+ ";

    NSString* nospacestring =[phno stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSString *kToNumber = nospacestring;
    NSString *kSMSMessage = @"Smart Child Info is a precautionary app designed to fight child abduction, exploitation, and maltreatment.";

    // Build request
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@:%@@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/%@/SMS/Messages/", kTwilioSID, kTwilioSecret, kTwilioSID];

    NSString *Loginurl = urlString;


    NSDictionary*
    dic=@{@"From":kFromNumber,@"To":kToNumber,@"Body":kSMSMessage};

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json",@"text/plain",@"application/xml",nil];

    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [manager POST:Loginurl parameters:dic progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {


        NSLog(@"Response from server  :  %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

        NSData * data = (NSData *)responseObject;
        NSString* xmlData = [NSString stringWithCString:[data bytes] encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",xmlData);

        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Message has been sent" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
        [alertController addAction:ok];

        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
          failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error)

     {

         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

         UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Failed" message:@"Message not sent" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

         UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
         [alertController addAction:ok];

         [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

     }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First up, we do not recommend you make API calls directly to the Twilio API from your iOS application. If someone were to unpack your application they could get access to your Account SID and Auth Token and then use your account for whatever they wanted.

Secondly, you are using the deprecated `SMS/Messages` endpoint. Instead, you should use the more up to date [`Messages` endpoint](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages).

I recommend you take a look at this blog post on [sending SMS messages with Twilio on iOS](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/11/how-to-send-an-sms-from-ios-in-swift.html). It covers how to set up a server to send your messages and then interacting with that server.